# How to take conditional back up of database in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgadmin-4

I am using postgres as database in my production system.
Version: psql (PostgreSQL) 12.9
Os: Ubuntu 18.04
PgAmin 4: version 6.4
Server instance: AWS RDS

My database is growing day by day and now it scales in GBs. i want to take back up of database in local system but the thing is not to take whole back up as production database is so big and i dont need some of the data as they are in GBs.

Example:

If my database has 5 tables,
table A, table B, table C, table D, table E

I want to take back up of schema(structure) of all table but not the data of all table.
Like,

| Table name | Schema | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table A | yes | Yes |
| Table B | yes | No |
| Table C | yes | No |
| Table D | yes | No |
| Table E | yes | Yes |

Here,

- Schema = yes means include schema of table in back up of database
- Schema = No means exclude schema of table in back up of database
- Data = yes means include data of table in back up of database
- Data = No means exclude data of table in back up of database

How can i take local back up like above mentioned way?
My aim is to ignore data of some table which have more data and scales in GBs.

Comment: If you are using a hosted service, don't they take backups for you?

Comment: pg_dump gives you all these options: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html